# How to write data to Firebase without override

Tags: swift, firebase

```
let value = categoriessegment.titleForSegment(at: categoriessegment.selectedSegmentIndex)
let data = ["price":pricetextfield.text,"Discount":Discounttextfield.text,"Category":value,"Description":descriptiontextfield.text];
// ref.child(currentdate).setValue(data)
ref.child(currentdate).updateChildValues(data as [AnyHashable : Any])
```

Comment: you mean if already data is present then don't insert, otherwise insert it?

Comment: i want to add data if the data is already present example i need to data add data for date 13-06-2019 for two times.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear as there is nothing in Firebase called an *override* and the comments are vague as well. Can you clarify and provide an example of your use case?

Comment: I need to add multiple entries for single node
e.g
For date 14-06-2019
1st entry- abc
2nd entry- xyz
3rd entry - pqr
like . this

Comment: To restate your question; you have a node with a key that's a date and you want to add multiple child nodes under that node. If that's the question, what difficulty are you having with that task? Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do? May even show us an example of what your Firebase structure should look like (as text please, no images).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Firebase SDK to only add data if already present, `updateChildValues` Update previous values or insert new values. To check if data already present you first need to get previous data, then you can check and take your decision. Like

```
   Database.database().reference().observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            if (snapshot.value != nil) {
                 // it means data already present
             } 
        })
```

We have another option to allow/disallow data overwriting through Firebase Rules like

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "your_node": {
        ".write": "data.exists()"   /// or ".write": "!data.exists()"  if you want to restrict overwrite
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Pravin This answer has some good info but is not 100% accurate. With [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) you can deny or allow data to be written to a node based on whether some other data already exists. For example, your Rules could be set up to deny a write if the node with the key '13-06-2019' doesn't exist. I am not sure that's the best solution as the use case is not clear but the answer is that yes, you can prevent/allow data being written if some other piece of data exists/doesn't exist.

Comment: Agreed, i only considered the firebase sdk, i'll update my answer and will add an example related to firebase rules.